# keyboardWillShow not respond

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, keyboard

here is problem, when i debug my program, i found keyboardWillShow function not responds every time. just first time, it will be called by program. here is my code, i dont know whats wrong in my code, but, when the keyboard first appeared, the function run well.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    /*
     Reduce the size of the text view so that it's not obscured by the keyboard.
     Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the appearance of the keyboard.
     */


    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    // Get the origin of the keyboard when it's displayed.
    NSValue* aValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    // Get the top of the keyboard as the y coordinate of its origin in self's view's coordinate system. The bottom of the text view's frame should align with the top of the keyboard's final position.
    CGRect keyboardRect = [aValue CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

    CGFloat keyboardTop = keyboardRect.origin.y;
    CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.textview.frame;

    newTextViewFrame.size.height = keyboardTop - self.view.bounds.origin.y;

    // Get the duration of the animation.
    NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

    // Animate the resize of the text view's frame in sync with the keyboard's appearance.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

    textview.frame = newTextViewFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    /*
     Restore the size of the text view (fill self's view).
     Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the disappearance of the keyboard.
     */
    NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    [animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

//    textview.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self save];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

and i regist notification

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
     object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
     object:nil];

}
```

and remove it in here

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [self save];
    self.textview = nil;
    self.title = nil;
    self.tags = nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];


}
```

i resign firstresponder, here is my code

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNote)] autorelease];

    [textview resignFirstResponder];


}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(save:)] autorelease];
    [self setUpUndoManager];

    return YES;


}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self save];
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: You need more info, do you release first responder? What is happening the second time etc

Comment: yes, i  resign FirstResponder, here is my code                                                               - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(save:)] autorelease];
    [self setUpUndoManager];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    
    return YES;

    
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self save];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}`

Comment: when the keyboard show in second time, the keyboardWillShow method isn't called automatically. in other words, keyboardWillShow method just run at the first time when the keyboard pop-up. after that, this method never run again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you are not writing any code to remove observer.....
Please provide keyboardWillHide method also....

Comment: i remove observer in viewDidUnload method. in fact, even though i don't remove it, the problem is still exist.

Comment: removing observer in viewDidUnload is cool....I do not understand one thing...why you have written  [textField resignFirstResponder];
in textFieldShouldBeginEditing...provide bit more about it.....

Comment: it may a little weird. i just want to make keyboard disappeared when user tap the textfield. but i know there is a conflict between keyboard appear and disappear action. i remove this method from my code. but the problem still has. i don't why in the first time, the every thing is good. the textfield scrolling is perfect. but after that, the textfield not scrolling. i found that through debug, the keyboardwillshow method never run after first time. the code for adjust textfield frame which i write in keyboardwillshow method. so that why the textfield not scrolling after first time.

Comment: your answer is correct. i checked my code again, i found i removed observer when i clean undomanager content. thanks for your help, my program run perfectly now.